# Quartz scheduler : JOB Executed more than once

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler to schedule my job. I have used CronTrigger. But the problem is there the trigger is getting fired more once. Here is my code to set up cron scheduler..

```
SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = null;
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = null;
        try {
            sched = schFactory.getScheduler();
            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("job1", "group1",SchedulerPBGC.class);

            String cronTimerStr = "* 16 15 * * ? *";

            LOG.warn("CRON TRIGGER FORMAT  FOR PROCESSING PB GC DATA:"+cronTimerStr);

            cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("SchedTrigger", "Group1", cronTimerStr);


            sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);          
            sched.start();

            LOG.warn("SCHEDULER REGISTERED FOR PROCESSING PB GC DATA :  TIME :"+cronTimerStr);          

        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            LOG.error("SchedulerException Message::"+se.getLocalizedMessage());     
        }
```

Here my scheduler executes the job 10 times...Here you can see the logs ..

```
2012-06-20 15:16:50,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:50,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:50,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:51,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:51,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:51,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:52,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:52,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:52,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:53,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:53,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:53,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:54,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:54,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:54,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:55,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:55,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:55,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:56,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:56,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:56,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:57,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:57,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:57,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:58,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:58,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:58,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:59,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION STARTED-----------------------
2012-06-20 15:16:59,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - The value of NO_OF_BEFORE_DAY_TO_RUN must be less then zero ..to start the scheduler
2012-06-20 15:16:59,001 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10 WARN  test.SchedulerPBGC - ----------PB GC SCHEDULER EXECUTION COMPLETED--------------------
```

How can i set the CronTimer iterator to 1 ? OR How can I stop the scheduler to executing the job more than once.

Any suggestion ?
Thanks,
Gunjan Shah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution ..

The cron syntax I have used is : String cronTimerStr = "* 16 15 * * ? *";

Here at 15:16 time, Quartz will initialize all possible workers for every second. So let say within that one minute (@ 16 min and 60 second), it will initialize maximum 60 threads.

I set the second parameter to zero.
   So the new syntax is "0 16 15 * * ? *".

Now it works fine.

Thanks,
Gunjan Shah.

Comment: Thanks, sounds obvious but I couldn't realize before :P